# How to get QVector<qint16> element from QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qvector

In my class parameters, I have created below qproperty:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QVector <qint16> tmrAndCont READ tmrAndCont WRITE setTmrAndCont NOTIFY tmrAndContChanged)
```

I have created the relatives methods for **get** and **read** property.
Now I have a QVector with 43 elements.

So my question is: can I access to the elements of my **QVector** from **QML**?

In main.cpp, I have declared the class and with engine.rootContext I show it to the QML.

```
Parameters::m_parameters = new Parameters();
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("parameters",Parameters::m_parameters);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QML has no notion of 16 bit integers. I suggest instead of exposing the vector as a context property directly, you wrap it in a `QObject` derived class that provides size, get and set methods and covert from and to regular `int` when you access the data, and expose that.

Note that QML will implicitly convert `QVector<int>` to a JS array, but for one thing, I haven't tested if this works for shorter integers and second, that will be conversion, meaning you will not be accessing the actual underlying data but a converted copy of it, meaning that you cannot set data and that if you have a local reference to the data, it will not reflect any changes, as it will refer to the old converted JS array object.